# Why is Docker disk space usage increasing when a container's output is piped to another process?

Tags: docker

Running the following command

```
docker run --rm alpine sh -c 'while true; do echo "asdasdasdasd"; done' | cat
```

and in another session:

```
watch df
```

seems to indicate that Docker is also writing the output (or something else?) to disk, which is rather surprising! Is there any way to not require using disk space for this? In my actual use case, filling disk space is unsustainable.

Comment: I'd imagine `docker logs` on this container still works, and Docker is probably persisting the container's output for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Docker records all output to `docker logs` by default, regardless of whether the output is redirected/piped or not.

Running

```
docker run --log-driver=none --rm alpine sh -c 'while true; do echo "asdasdasdasd"; done' | cat
```

works like I assumed the original command would. :)